# Jboss 7 AS is not printing my System.out.println("Anything"); in Linux machine

Tags: linux, jboss

Jboss 7 AS is not printing my System.out.println("Anything"); in Linux machine.
here are my configurations:-

**Linux:-**"Linux MachineName 2.6.32-573.22.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 17 03:23:39 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

**JBOSS:-** 7 AS

**Java:-** jdk1.7.0_79
The same server is printing my System.out.println("Anything"); in windows machine but not in linux.

I will able to provide any other information you want.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there

after posting here i tried it on with jboss-logging.jar file, and it started working,
download jboss-logging.jar for any jboss server (5,6,7) and put it in following location:-

**{JBOSSHOME}/modules/encryptdecryptstring/main**

don't forget to put the entry of same file in module.xml

please do share your experience if you still face any issues
Thanks,